# Deformation after merging by distance

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, multiresolution, blender-osm

I'm facing a problem with a mesh that has a Multiresolution modifier applied. Everything was progressing well as I worked on the UV mapping. In an attempt to eliminate any duplicate vertices in the mesh, I opted to merge them by distance, which resulted in the merging of two vertices. Unfortunately, this action has caused an issue when viewing the mesh in Object mode, and it appears to be irreparable. Kindly review the images depicting the mesh before and after. Could someone please provide assistance with this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The modifier is not applied. You could delete it and create another. It's also possible to apply it at higher subdivision and then use "unsubdivide" when you re-add it so you don't loose detail. The term "apply" means to bake it into geometry when we are talking about modifiers. It's done by pressing ctrl+a while hovering over it. You wouldn't say you "applied" it yet, you could say you just "added" it or simply you are "using" it.

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys Applying the modifier before merging by distance proved to be helpful. Thank you so much.